# determine the interval in which the solution is defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE is $dr/d(\theta)$ = $r^2/\theta,$ $r(1) = 2$

separable equation and integrate both sides: $\int(dr/r^2$ - $\int d\theta/\theta$ =$0$

-$\frac{1}{r} - ln(\theta) = c$

solve for c:  $-\frac{1}{2} - ln(1) = c$ 
 -$\frac{1}{2}$ = c

plug back into equation:  -$\frac{1}{r} - ln(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}$

solve for r: 
$r = \frac{2}{1-2ln(\theta)}$

My quetion is, how do I find the interval for the solution?

Comment: maybe you wanted to type $\ln(1)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you need $\ln(\theta)$ to be defined, and you also can't let the denominator be $0$.